# Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. Can't find MagickWand.h on Solus

Tags: rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm using `Solus 3`, and `ruby 2.5.1` with `rvm`, and I can't install `rmagick` gem, because it says:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/nintf1link/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@rmagic/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
/home/nintf1link/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180909-30633-ddpzbp.rb extconf.rb
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
checking for pkg-config... yes
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no
checking for presence of MagickWand API (ImageMagick version >= 6.9.0)... no
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/nintf1link/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/nintf1link/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@rmagic/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/rmagick-2.16.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/nintf1link/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@rmagic/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/nintf1link/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@rmagic/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

By the way, I can't install imagemagick 6 or less, because this lib is needed by other programs on the system... Any idea?

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick 7 or 6 installed. It may be that RMagick needs IM 6 and you may have IM 7 installed. Or perhaps the other way around. But it looks like it might be a mismatch on the ImageMagick version and RMagick

Comment: The `checking for Magick-config... no` tells me that you don't have the development package installed. You'll have to install `imagemagick-devel` before attempting to install `rmagick`. As @fmw42 pointed out, ImageMagick 6 -vs- 7 is important, so check which version the gem is expecting (the log suggestion IM-6).

Comment: @emcconville Hi, I already installed and still isn't working